How to restore Event Log Files or view Blue screens without the Event Log Files?
Someone else deleted my Event Logs with the following command:
 wevtutil el | Foreach-Object {wevtutil cl "$_"}

I wanted to know whether Blue screens occurred while those people had my PC.
Can I restore the Event Logs?
Is there any other possibility to view if Blue screens occurred?

Unlikely -- as soon as an active Event Log is cleared, the next event ion that log overwrites any data that might have been recoverable.

In addition to creating event log entries, blue screens also create minidump files by default in %SystemRoot%\Minidump, which you can inspect using the handy tool Nirsoft BlueScreenView. Of course, these .dmp files could also have been manually deleted, so absence of these files is not a guarantee of no blue screens.
